# How to open Windows Jabber client to a particular endpoint

Tags: command-line, jabber

How can Pidgin be started with a chat window already opened to talk to a certain client? Our goal is to open Jabber chat from a Contact list web application.

Something like: `pidgin.exe -talkto:JABBER_ID`

Could this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I sounds like something you would like to realise through an IM: URL. You can do something like:

> `<a href=”im:<sip:jack@cisco.com>”>Click Here to IM Jack</a>`

See reference here [EnableIMProtocolHandler](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/jabber/10_5/CJAB_BK_D6497E98_00_deployment-installation-guide-ciscojabber/CJAB_BK_D6497E98_00_deployment-installation-guide-ciscojabber_chapter_01001.html)